# ¿Cómo se pronuncia "Camus" en español?

Tags: traducción, pronunciación, extranjerismos, francés

Albert Camus en francés se pronuncia /albɛʁ kamy/ (con u francesa y sin pronunciar la s), pero me pregunto, ¿cómo se "castellaniza" su pronunciación?

Al igual que Jean-Paul Sartre lo pronunciamos (en español de España) como /yampol sartre/ y no /ʒɑ̃ pɔl saʁtʁ/, o a Simone de Beauvoir (en francés /simɔn də bovwaʁ/) la llamamos /simon de bobua/, ¿cuál sería la convención para Albert Camus en este caso? ¿/kami/, /kamu/? (Pronunciado como "Camí"/"Camú").

Muchas gracias.

Nota: Sé que lo más correcto sería pronunciarlo con la /y/ original (yo personalmente no tengo ninguna dificultad en pronunciar ese fonema), pero me parece un poco "pedante" por decirlo de alguna manera pronunciarlo en francés, especialmente en una conversación informal.

Answer (score 4):

#### Respuesta corta

La RAE, en Twitter, [dice claramente que](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/304225870334275586?lang=en)

> La pronunciación de los nombres propios extranjeros tiende a respetar la que se les da en su lengua de origen.

por lo que yo tendería a intentar imitar la pronunciación francesa.

#### Respuesta más larga

El DPD tiene un [artículo](https://www.rae.es/dpd/ayuda/tratamiento-de-los-extranjerismos) algo más extenso sobre la pronunciación y ortografía de extranjerismos, donde se dividen los extranjerismos en "superfluos" y "necesarios". Los nombres propios son, claramente, necesarios (no hay una palabra equivalente española). Dentro de los necesarios, el artículo dice que "se aplican dos criterios, según los casos:"

> 2.1. ***Mantenimiento de la grafía y pronunciación originarias***. Se trata de extranjerismos asentados en el uso internacional en su forma original, como *ballet, blues, jazz* o *software* [...]

Esta sería la opción recomendada por la RAE en Twitter para nombres propios (que cumplen el criterio de estar "asentados en el uso internacional en su forma original"), es decir, **pronunciar /kamy/**.

> 2.2. ***Adaptación de la pronunciación o de la grafía originarias.*** La mayor parte de las veces se proponen adaptaciones cuyo objetivo prioritario es preservar el alto grado de cohesión entre forma gráfica y pronunciación característico de la lengua española. La adaptación de estas voces se ha hecho por dos vías:
>
> a) Mantenimiento de la grafía original, pero con pronunciación a la española y acentuación gráfica según las reglas del español [...]

En nuestro caso, esto nos llevaría a decir **/kamus/**. Aunque no es la opción recomendada, quizá puede servir en determinados casos, sobre todo si se piensa que los oyentes no van a entender la pronunciación extranjera.

> b) Mantenimiento de la pronunciación original, pero adaptando la forma extranjera al sistema gráfico del español [...]

Esto nos llevaría a decir **/kamy/** como los franceses, y escribir algo como "Camí". No parece una buena idea para nombres propios.

La opción de escribir "Camus" y decir /kami/ no parece estar contemplada.